# Write Array and Variable to Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, numpy

I have an array in the format `[27.214 27.566]` - there can be several numbers. Additionally I have a Datetime variable.

```
now=datetime.now()   
datetime=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   
time.sleep(0.5)   
agilent.write("MEAS:TEMP? (@101:102)")   
values = np.fromstring(agilent.read(), dtype=float, sep=',')
```

The output from the array is [27.214 27.566]

Now I would like to write this into a dataframe with the following structure:

`Datetime, FirstValueArray, SecondValueArray, ....`

How to do this? In the dataframe every one minute a new array is added.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. Please post a sample input with expected output.

Comment: I have edit the post

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want to append a row to an existing dataframe `df` with appropriate columns : `value1, value2, ..., lastvalue, datetime`
We can easily convert the array to a series :
`s = pd.Series(array)`

What you want to do next is append the datetime value to the series :
`s.append(datetime, ignore_index=True)` cf [Series.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html#pandas.Series.append)

Now you have a series whose length matches `df.columns`. You want to convert that series to a dataframe to be able to use `pd.concat` :
`df_to_append = s.to_frame().T`

We need to get the transpose of the original dataframe, because `Series.to_frame()` returns a dataframe with the series as a single column, and we want a single index but multiple columns.

Before you concatenate, however, you need to make sure both those dataframes columns names match, or it will create additional columns :

`df_to_append.columns = df.columns`

Now we can concatenate our two dataframes :

`pd.concat([df, df_to_append], ignore_index=True)` cf [pandas.Concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

For further details, see [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)